# assessing system/server performance through metric beat- elastisearch

Tags: elasticsearch, metricbeat

I have implemented ELK stack for logging solutions and aslo set up metricbeat for measuring server performance. I stumbled on system module's "system.cpu.user.pct" which is the system's cpu usage. Now, I need to understand what are the other fields that contribute in this value. I have other fields such as "system.cpu.cores","system.cpu.idle.pct","system.cpu.iowait.pct","system.cpu.irq.pct","system.cpu.nice.pct","system.cpu.softirq.pct","system.cpu.steal.pct","system.cpu.system.pct","system.cpu.user.pct" under the metric set **cpu**. But most of them have value "0". 
I am trying to understand:

1. Does the field "system.cpu.user.pct" represent the server usage
2. If yes, what fields actually contribute to the changing values of
   "system.cpu.user.pct"